# Parsing list value in a dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse data with RE. The data I have to parse are:

```
  "comments":
{

[
{ "id" : "001",
  "x" : "2",
  "name" : "Chuck"
} ,
{ "id" : "009",
  "x" : "7",
  "name" : "Chuck"
} 
]

}
```

Using urllib I copy the text above into a string, but I don't want all the text. I just want this:

```
[
{ "id" : "001",
  "x" : "2",
  "name" : "Chuck"
} ,
{ "id" : "009",
  "x" : "7",
  "name" : "Chuck"
}
]
```

I have tried using regular expressions but I think I am doing something wrong. My regular expression is:

```
y = re.findall("([.])", html)
```

I interpret it as finding all characters between `[` and `]` and saving it in `y`.

Comment: what is your data's type? why do you think you need regex?

Comment: Have you tried reading up on basic regex syntax? You'll quickly see that `[` and `]` have special meaning.

Comment: It is JSON, but I want to copy it into a string (only the wanted part) and then I will operate using JSON with it

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that is the point, for example [0-9] will match all the numbers that it finds, but what about finding the character "[" and "]" and also everything between them? That is why I tried with ([.]) but it seems not working because [] are special characters

Comment: Why not just parse it as JSON?

Comment: Looks like malformed JSON.

Comment: Yes it is more logical to do it as JSON, but I am reading the information from a html (it is just an exercise to learn about JSON) and there is a header giving me problems if I do it directly as JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One way: Add braces around the text and parse as JSON
- Another way: regex `\[[^\]]+\]`
- Third way: extract by hands `x[x.find('['):x.find(']')]`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape the brackets with a backslash, and note the `.` as repeating (but not including the closing bracket) with `?`. Use the `re.DOTALL` flag to make `.` include newlines. You can then send this string to `ast.literal_eval()` to evaluate it:

```
import re
import ast
s = '''  "comments":
{

[
{ "id" : "001",
  "x" : "2",
  "name" : "Chuck"
} ,
{ "id" : "009",
  "x" : "7",
  "name" : "Chuck"
} 
]

}'''
```

Result:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(re.search(r'\[.*?\]', s, re.DOTALL).group(0))
[{'name': 'Chuck', 'x': '2', 'id': '001'}, {'name': 'Chuck', 'x': '7', 'id': '009'}]
```